# SQL Server not passing decimal value through to C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to call a function that returns a decimal value to my C# website. When I call the function inside SQL Server the trailing decimal values are present. But when it gets passed into C# the trailing decimals are missing.

This is my SQL Server stored procedure being called:

```
declare @MonthlyTotal as decimal(10,2)
set @MonthlyTotal=(select cast((Linetotal * Subtotal) as decimal(10,2)))
return @MonthlyTotal
```

Inside my C# server code I am receiving the stored procedure value. But it does not come with the trailing decimals.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection);

SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();
cmd4.Connection = sqlConnection;
cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd4.CommandText = "GetTBSMonthlyTotalService";

SqlParameter JobParam = new SqlParameter("MonthlyTotal", SqlDbType.Decimal, 10);
JobParam.Precision = 10;
JobParam.Scale = 2;
JobParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

cmd4.Parameters.Add(JobParam);

try
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
}

cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();

double ID = Double.Parse((cmd4.Parameters[0].Value.ToString()));
sqlConnection.Close();
return ID;
```

Comment: You are using double, `decimal` should map to `decimal` type in .Net framework. Also what are the trailing values are they `.00` ?

Comment: The trailing values are not 00. In this particular case they are `.44`. So I should change my C# value to `Decimal` also?

Comment: @MethodMan I am using the SqlParameter.Percision

Comment: @ChaseErnst perhaps you need to re-evaluate this line and use the correct datatype `double ID = Double.Parse((cmd4.Parameters[0].Value.ToString()));`

Comment: The value is already a double.  Why call ToString on it, then parse that?  Just cast the bastid.

Comment: I `.ToString()` it because it needs to be in a string type to be parsed. Otherwise C# throws and error if I just try `double ID = cm4.Paramteres[1].Value;`

Comment: I am aware of how to use the TryParse. But why should I use tryparse if In know the value coming accross will always be a double?

Comment: Also, in order to `TryParse` an object I would still need to user `ToString()`  on the object.

Comment: The **return value** of a stored procedure must always be **INT** - and it should be used as an error (or: no error) indicator. If you want to return a decimal value - use an `OUTPUT` parameter or a `SELECT` statement from the stored procedure

Comment: Sorry? But why `Linetotal * Subtotal`... that is very weird.  Why would you multiply linetotal by the subtotal?  Normally Subtotal = sum of all linetotals.

Comment: @marc_s is right - you are misusing the return value; you should be using an output param instead.

Comment: Ahah! Thank you this worked! thank you, I have actually had this problem in the past. Totally forgot about it. Submit your answer and I will mark it as correct!

Comment: @JK This is not actually what I am doing. What I am doing isde my select statement was much more complicated, I just wanted to simplify it for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **return value** of a stored procedure can only be an integer type (`INT`, `BIGINT` - see the [relevant MSDN docs on `RETURN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)) and it's only used to signal success (or failure) of the stored procedure.

If you need to return anything else - including decimal - you need to use either an `OUTPUT` parameter, or a `SELECT` statement that selects that value as a result set for the stored procedure.