# C# double to Sql Server decimal(x,y) mapping

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

C# `Double` is not the exact data type map for Sql Server `Decimal(X,Y)`, it in fact maps to `float(53)`. As mentioned on the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6dee81ab-b205-48cb-9058-37a2eec0eb6e/what-datatype-is-best-float-double-or-decimal?forum=sqldatabaseengine), `float / Real` data types in Sql Server are an approximation, they can always lead to different results for same data processing, which can cause lot of issues especially in the financial applications.

In our case we have defined the Sql Server columns with decimal point precision requirement as `Decimal(X,Y)` and mapping the same to C# `Double`, but it is leading to unpredictable results as data is persisted to the Sql Server, many times data is truncated and few times it is marginally lower or higher.

We have tried adding an extra number beyond decimal, so that truncation doesn't impact, some thing like if the column is decimal(10,2), we instead of saving `6.23`, try to save `6.233`, but that doesn't help, as it may still not persist `6.23`, sometimes it is `6.24` or `6.22`

What are our options, if we want to retain the C# Double and Sql Server Decimal(X,Y). May be using C# `Decimal` can help, but our values are no where near double's limit itself, so in my view Decimal would be sheer waste of memory, though if it provides correct results, we may still consider.

Our main challenge is no change / modification in the data persisted and we would be more keen to make changes on C# side as that's more in our control, not the database schema, but any good suggestion is welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180133/sql-server-not-passing-decimal-value-through-to-c-sharp

Comment: That's not my question,  mine is more about double to decimal mapping without any kind of data loss

Comment: Don't use floating points (including `double`s) if you need precision. Use `decimal`s.

Comment: Sql DECIMAL(X,Y) maps to .Net Decimal. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JLRishe does using decimals can have a performance impact on the system, also memory wise wouldn't float / double more prudent

Comment: @MrinalKamboj You're talking about micro-optimizations. If precision is a concern, then I think there are very few situations where a 64-bit vs. 128-bit difference in the size of some of your variables should matter.

Comment: My question is WHY do you NEED to map double to decimal if Sql Server types have direct corresponding types in .Net?